# Non blocking process with Shiny for python

Tags: python, web, python-asyncio, py-shiny

I want to test if Shiny for python app is truly async such that a user can interact with a Shiny for python web app, even when another concurrent user accessing the same app is running a long running process. I thought it is possible but somehow my example code does not indicate so. Is there something wrong with my example code,  or my assumption is wrong?

```
from shiny import App, reactive, ui
from asyncio import sleep

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
ui.input_action_button("show1", "Show1"),
ui.input_action_button("show2", "Show2"),
)

def server(input, output, session):

    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.show1)
    async def _():
        ui.notification_show("Message 1")
        print("sleep 1", session)
        await sleep(5)
        print("sleep 1 finished", session)
        ui.notification_show("Warning message1", type="warning")
    
    
    @reactive.Effect
    @reactive.event(input.show2)
    async def _():
        ui.notification_show("Message 2")
        print("sleep 2", session)
        await sleep(5)
        print("sleep 2 finished", session)
        ui.notification_show("Warning message2", type="warning")

app = App(app_ui, server, debug=False)
```

My test is as follows:

1. Run the app in a browser tab as user 1. Press Show1.
2. Within 5s, run the app in another browser tab as user 2. Press Show2.

Observation: The second tab always show the notification after the first tab finished showing the warning. Similarly, the printout shows similar effect that async is not in action.